# Show div if not already visible

Tags: jquery, visibility, hidden

I have some code which adds text to the div then shows it.

```
$("#messageBox").addClass('msg-error').text("Your selected date is no longer available due to the appointment duration. Please select an alternative date.").show();
```

I then have some other code which also adds text to the same div and shows it.

```
$("#messageBox").addClass('msg-error').text("Your selected time is no longer available due to the appointment duration. Please select an alternative time.").show();
```

However I only want the bottom message to be displayed if the messageBox div is not already visible. My code for this is.

```
if($("#messageBox").not(':visible') || $("#messageBox").css("visibility") == "hidden"){
    $("#messageBox").addClass('msg-error').text("Your selected time is no longer available due to the appointment duration. Please select an alternative time.").show();
}
```

It does not always seem to work, am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
if($("#messageBox").is(':hidden')){
    // your existing code
}
```

Or Alternately

```
if($("#messageBox").is(':visible') === false){
    // your existing code
}
```

Hope this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

If these are the only ways you toggle the visibility then the simplest option is to just check if the div `#messageBox` already has the class `msg-error`.

```
if(!$('#messageBox').hasClass("msg-error")) {
    $("#messageBox").addClass('msg-error').text("Your selected time is no longer available due to the appointment duration. Please select an alternative time.").show();
}
```